# Linux install on HP t5565 Thin Client

Tags: hp

I am trying to install latest version using USB on above hardware. I get a codec error. Unit has 1GB flash and 1Gb RAM. Flash was wiped by auction house, I bought 55 units.  If there is an alternative to install image I would appreciate it. Downloading XPE now to see if that helps.